# How to delete the current div in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js and I want to delete the current `div` that is generated in a `map` function. When I click on delete button it deletes the **last** element of the array array instead of the clicked element.

Here is my code:

```
{            
    this.state.array.map((item,index)=>{
                  return(
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Question />
                      <button onClick={() => { this.deleteRow(index); }}>DELETE</button>
                     </div>
                  );
                })
              }
```

and this is my delete function

```
    deleteRow = (index) => {
        // make new rows. note: react state is immutable.
        let newArray = this.state.array;
       newArray.pop(newArray[index]);
        this.setState({
          array: newArray,
        });
        console.log(this.state.array);
      }
```

Comment: `pop` removes the last element of the array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: `let newArray = this.state.array` this is not a new array. All you're doing is creating a reference to the same array. To create a new array you can use the spread operator like so `let newArray = [...this.state.array]`. Right now you are mutating state by operating on `newArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <button onClick={() => this.deleteRow(item)}>DELETE</button>
```

change this code

```
deleteRow = (item) => {
    let newArray = this.state.array;
    let filtered = newArray.filter(a=>a.id!==item.id);
    this.setState({array: filtered});
  }
```